# How to get Partial Product Key of MS Office in CPP

Tags: c++, windows, vbscript, ms-office

I have tried this..

open cmd
using command
`cscript "C:\Program Files \Microsoft office\Office14\ospp.vbs" \dstatus`

Giving Partial Product Key EX(XYZA)

There are lots of tool available like: KeyFinderInstaller,isunshare-product-key-finder

I am looking C++ API.

I have also Tried

1. MsiGetProductProperty
2. MsiGetComponentPath
3. MsiGetProductCode

There is no API to get Partial Product Key.

Comment: You can start a process with command line you provided and replace it's `STDOUT` with a pipe, from which then you will read your output.

Answer (score 0):

Thank everybody,

Yes!. We can Get Partial Product key by class "SoftwareLicensingProduct"
This class has a member PartialProductKey.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc534596(v=vs.85).aspx